# R forecasting: List of supported or available models from fable package

Tags: r, forecasting

Is there a complete list of all available models within fable package?

```
https://rdrr.io/cran/fabletools/man/model.html
model(
    snaive = SNAIVE(Turnover),
    ets = ETS(log(Turnover) ~ error("A") + trend("A") + season("A")),
    arima = ARIMA(Turnover)
  )
```

From the examples, only 3 models are available, which I find quite limited compared to the forecast package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reference page on the fable website contains an organised list of models: https://fable.tidyverts.org/reference/

Comment: Hi Mitchelle, do you also have list of models which are supported by fable syntax? I'm aware of prophet fable, but hopefully want to discover others as well. I like the unified approach that fable is developing, though I think there're still some models which are not yet supported within fable or someone has developed it but not documented within fable reference page (prophet as an example)

Comment: Currently the additional extension packages are fasster, fable.prophet, and fable.bsts. As this list grows, a centralised list of packages like https://exts.ggplot2.tidyverse.org/ would be useful, but this does not yet exist.

Comment: Thanks for the fable.bsts! Remember reading the request from Github issue, but didn't know it was implemented.

Comment: Thanks to David Holt for that one: https://github.com/davidtedfordholt/fable.bsts

Answer (score 3):

The most reliable way of understanding the capabilities of a package is, as always its CRAN page. In the specific case of [the `fable` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=fable), we find [its reference manual](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fable/fable.pdf) and two different vignettes, [one introduction](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fable/vignettes/fable.html) and [one vignette on forecasting with transformations](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fable/vignettes/transformations.html).

The reference manual in particular looks helpful. For instance, I see no less than ten `fitted.*()` functions:

```
> library(dplyr)
> ls(getNamespace("fable"), all.names=TRUE) %>%
+ grep(pattern="fitted",value=TRUE)
[1] "fitted.AR"         "fitted.ARIMA"      "fitted.croston"   
[4] "fitted.ETS"        "fitted.model_mean" "fitted.NNETAR"    
[7] "fitted.RW"         "fitted.TSLM"       "fitted.VAR"
```

True, not all of them are very different (`fitted.AR()` vs. `fitted.ARIMA()`), but there are quite a few more than you mention (e.g., `fitted.NNETAR()`, `fitted.fable_theta()` or `fitted.croston()`).

Also note that `fable` is the successor package to `forecast`, so over time, it will likely accumulate more models.

Comment: Thanks for the new trick on using the namespace.
I'm aware of CRAN and the reference page but I doubt its accuracy. For example, prophet is not found either on the reference page nor in the fable reference page. Theta is also named differently, in reference page it's THETA but in the namespace it's fable_theta.